# Counting participation by day

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a solution to this problem, but I don't know if its the BEST way to go about it so I'm looking for better alternatives.

I'm trying to count participation by day between two weeks

So two people participate in a sport over 2 weeks

Person A 
Person b

Week 1

```
Day 1: A, b
DAY 2: A, b
Day 3: a, b
Day 4: a, b
Day 5: a, b
```

Week 2

```
Day 1: A, B
DAY 2: A
DAY 3: A
Day 4: A, B
Day 5: B
```

So I want to know how many participants I lost compared to the previous week
So the output would look like

LOSS: DAY 1: 0, Day 2: 1, Day 3: 1, Day 4: 0, Day 5: 1

So what I'm currently doing is a subquery in the where caluse and using not in and looping through the days like those

```
DECLARE @days table (d TIN

INSERT INTO @days
     VALUES(1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7)

SELECT COUNT(Person), DayOfWeek
FROM participation
WHERE WEEK = Week1
AND DAY = @day
AND PERSON NOT IN (SELECT Person
                   FROM participation
                   WHERE WEEK = Week2
                   and Day = @day)
```

**Figured it out**

Used a very very similar method to the answer below

```
  WITH CTE AS
(SELECT dayofweek, person
 FROM Participation
 Where week = week1)

   SELECT DayOfWeek, COunt(CTE.Person), COunt(a.Person)
   FROM CTE
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT DayOfWeek, Person
          FROM Participation
          where week = week2)a
   ON a.Person = CTE.Person
   and a.dayofweek = cte.dayofweek
```

I put that into a #table with a calculated column and then get the min of each day and I have my answer. Thanks for the help

Comment: No way that works.  day = @day?   You have a table of @days.   WEEK = Week1 ?

Comment: @Paparazzi sorry It didn't add a block of code I had in there

Answer (score 1):

You want to avoid loops in SQL - although I can't see said loop in your code. Are you using a cursor to populate @day?

Anyway, I'm not sure about your data types (or the table structure) but assuming `week` is a string and everything is stored in one `participation` table then this will get you the loss from week 1 to week 2:

```
;with cte_people ( week, DayOfWeek, person_count)
as
(
     select  WEEK, DayOfWeek, count(person)
     from participation
     group by WEEK, DayOfWeek
)

select c1.DayOfWeek, c1.person_count - c2.person_count as loss
from cte_people c1
inner join cte_people c1
on c2.DayOfWeek = c1.DayOfWeek
and c2.week = 'Week2'
where c1.week = 'Week1'
```

Comment: It won't let me add the query with the loop, but I figured it out similar to yours

    with CTE AS
    ( SELECT DayOfWeek, Person
      FROM Participation
      WHERE Week = week1)

SELECT cte.PERSON, CTE.DayOfWeek, Count(cte.Person), COUNT(a.Person)
FROM CTE
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Dayofweek, person
                    FROM participation
                     WHERE DayofWeek = week2) a
on a.person = cte.person
and a.dayofweek = cte.dayofweeK

I inserted that into a table with a computed column took the min of each day and viola got what I wanted minus the loop